# Using char as array index after using map

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dictionary

I am trying to use character as index for an array of integers after mapping it. The problem is whenever I try to access the array using a variable of type char(as array[char]), instead of using array["], I am getting error from compiler. I wonder if it is necessary to use constant types after mapping.
Here is my code.

```
        int count=0;
        int length=strlen(word);
        std::map<std::string, int, std::less<std::string> >  alpha;
        alpha["X"]=1;
        alpha["Y"]=2;
        alpha["Z"]=3;
        char temp;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
        temp=word[i];
        count=alpha[temp];
        }
```

Error(s) :

error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'char' to 'std::map, int, std::less > >::key_type&& {aka std::basic_string&&}' [-fpermissive]
count=alpha[temp];

error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]' [-fpermissive]
basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc());

Comment: Don't confuse `char` and `std::string`.

Comment: "A" is the string literal, 'A' is the character literal. If you want to use chracters as index, make sure to use the correct literal.

Comment: Also, if you're using C++, there are few good reasons to call `strlen` when there's a perfectly good length-finding method on `std::string`...

Comment: Also, `count=alpha[temp];` will add an entry to the map if the key value `temp` doesn't exist.  Is this the behavior you were intending?

Comment: PaulMcKenzie, nope, I was trying to use temp as an index, whereby temp is an alphabet from word.
Rook, I was not using strings strictly as strings, but more primitive char array. Although, I have difficulty in switching data types between php,perl,C and java.
πάνταῥεῖ, Jan, Got it, although I thought that there will be automatic type conversion.

Comment: @Siddharth - You are changing the map when you use `[]` and the key doesn't exist.  Just because it is on the right side of the `=` sign doesn't change that fact.  It is a separate issue, but an issue nevertheless.  Just warning you not to be surprised when you see your map at the end of the loop with empty entries you didn't expect.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I actually confused char with string, the key, i.e. char variable here was supposed to work as an index, but I defined string as index, which created the confusion. While looking at that statement alone, it might look like I am calling something mapped to temp, but I was actually calling something which is mapped to the value of temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatic conversion from `char` to `std::string`. You have two options:

- make the conversion explicit, `count=alpha[std::string(1,temp)];`
- change the type of `temp` to `std::string`. You *can* assign a `char` to a `string`, with the intuitive result, so the rest of your code will work

If *all* the map keys are single-character strings, then you might consider using `char` as the key; or even using a flat array large enough for any character value you might need.

Comment: I decided to go with changing data type of temp instead of explicit type conversion. Thank you.